# App crashed error heroku deploying django

Tags: django, heroku

I deployed django app on heroku and got an error - h10 app crashed, but didn't get any info about reason of this error:

[image]

Comment: This isn't possible to debug. First, you should post error messages as text, not images. Second, if you check heroku's logs (either via the cli or the web dashboard), you might get extra details.

Comment: post the whole error message as text.